# How to remove an element by tag matching

Tags: python, html, django

I want to remove the part surrounded by a specific element / class from the variable storing html, but I do not know how.

For example, the following html document is stored in the variable "content"

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>content</h1>
  <p>content<p>
  <p>content</p>
<div>

<!-- want to delete from here -->
<div class="Footer">
 <div class=Footer-item>
  ...
  ...

 </div>
</div>
```

I tried implementing as below

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

newcontent = content.find("div", {"class":"Footer"}).extract()
```

However, the following error occurred

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

If you have a good solution please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup to parse html documents.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = "......<div class='footer'> ...</div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup,"html.parser")
other_tags = soup

soup.find('div',class_='footer').decompose()

print (other_tags)
```